# Scrolling site doesn't work in Mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, scroll, mobile-safari

I have a single-page scrolling website.  It uses a fixed-position nav bar with jquery to scroll to different sections of the website.  The site works fine except for on the iOS (I haven't tested it on Android).  On iOS, after clicking a link, the navigation freezes until you manually scroll up or down. For some reason the link stays active until you scroll.  Is this a bug in Mobile Safari?  Is there some workaround?

Here's the basic HTML:

```
<body>
  <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>

<div class = "page" id = "home"> </div>

<!-- About -->
<div class = "page" id="about">
<div class="pagebreak"></div>

</div>

<!-- Portfolio -->
<div class = "page" id="portfolio">
<div class="pagebreak"></div>

</div>

<!-- Contact Me -->
<div class = "page" id="contact">
    <div class="pagebreak"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here's the actual site if you would like to see the problem: http://boundincode.com

BTW, I don't think this is a jquery or javascript issue because even if I remove the javascript and the jquery, the problem persists.

Comment: Works fine for me on my iPhone 4 (5.0.1), what's your iOS version?

Comment: If you click a link, can you immediately click another link?  I'm using 5.0.1 as well.  But on my phone I can only click one link without the link freezing

Comment: Oh, my bad. Now I see the problem. No I can't, but sometimes I do get pushed a bit in the right direction. I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked on other websites that scroll down a single page and they seem to have the same issue.  It seems like it's a bug in mobile safari.  Maybe someone has an idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add another answer since it's completely separate from my original one.

Since you need a temporary workaround, you might find what you're looking for in [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). I'd used it to do what you're trying to accomplish in pre-iOS 5 days so it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` support was only added to Mobile Safari in iOS 5, so it's likely that the implementation of it is still buggy, especially if you're seeing the same problem in other sites. Probably worth filing a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into filing a report, now I just need to find a workaround temporarily...